# Создание растрового графического редактора на С# (художественные кисти)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, графика, рисование

у меня готова базовая программа в Visual Studio, с пикчербоксом, на который передаётся линия с помощью класса Pen за счёт смены координат мыши.

как вместо Pen создать кисть из своего файла "наконечника", которая будет иметь прозрачность (и полупрозрачность) рисовать точечно с заданными промежутками, не зависящими от скорости проведения мыши (и другими свойствами, как угол наклона)?

использование TextureBrush не помогло, оно создаёт мощёную изображением заливку линии, а не накладываемые друг на друга точки.

каким способом грамотнее всего реализовать такую функцию, которая используется в большинстве растровых редакторов?
кроме последнего Пейнта, там скорее векторная система, когда единое изображение мазка искривляется за счёт проводимой линии. это интересно, но не то что мне сейчас нужно.

я ищу способ как в Фотошопе:

[image: пример кисти из фотошопа]

[image: пример кисти из Пейнта]

я новичок, и надеюсь на вашу помощь, так как в интернете почти ничего об этой теме не нашла.

Comment: Какой тип приложения вы не скажете, и код вы не покажете? Что именно не получается? Что пробовали, как оно работает или не работает? Например в WPF есть готовый контрол InkCanvas, который уже умеет вот это вот все из коробки.

Comment: Наверняка у вас WinForms. Это сильно устаревший фреймворк и сделать на нём продвинутый графический редактор всегда было нетривиальной задачей. Если вы просто учитесь, то можете продолжить. Но лучше сменить его на что-нибудь другое. Я бы советовал сразу брать новейший MAUI (preview уже можно пощупать).